# SNI in pure-ftpd

Tags: centos, sni, pureftpd

I'm looking for SNI support in pure-ftpd. I found some documentation here: https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.TLS

Please read section CUSTOM CERTIFICATE HANDLERS in the above link. It specifies the use of service pure-certd. But I cannot find a way to install this service.

Please help me to find a way to install it. Os used is Centos 7. Pure-ftpd version: pure-ftpd v1.0.47 [privsep]

Comment: You may need to upgrade to CentOS 8, where pure-certd is part of the pure-ftpd package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNI support was not present in pure-ftpd 1.0.47. It was [added in 1.0.48](https://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd/news/#version-1-0-48-released).

You should upgrade to CentOS 8, for which EPEL already includes the latest version of Pure-FTPd (1.0.49) with SNI support.